# pass contents of ViewModel to Details page from Index in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Inside of my controller, `bazController`, I am returning a list of`bazViewModels` to be displayed on the `Index` page.

Now, when I click on the `Details` link for each item in the `bazViewModel` is there a way I can pass that particular viewmodel `item` to the `Details` page?

I can pass the necessary data from my view model through the URL, but I would prefer not to.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd only send some kind of ID to the Details action, e.g. the link would look like /products/details/15 to display details on the product with ID 17. The Detail action would then fetch the required data using the id as a key, for example from a database or the session.

However, you can create your own ModelBinder to make this happen automatically, along those lines:

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("id");

        var id = int.Parse(val.AttemptedValue);

        return LoadFromDatabase(id);
    }
}
```

So your action could look like:

```
    public ViewResult Details(MyModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: My problem is one of the fields is not known until the Index page loads and `usertype` is calculated based upon the user account accessing the page. 

`usertype` is not stored in the database due to its variable nature.

Comment: You could store it in the session then. Either under a fixed key or a dynamically created key that you pass to the details action to look up the proper value.

Answer (score 0):

use `TempData` to pass information from one page to other and this will be cleared after use on that page

Edit:
Can also use `session` but make sure session get cleared after it is used.